# Pandas Ordered Categorical not working as intended

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D'],
                  index=['excellent', 'excellent', 'excellent', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'poor', 'poor'])
df.rename(columns={0: 'Grades'}, inplace=True)

cat_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+'], ordered=True)

print(df['Grades'].astype(cat_dtype))

print(df['Grades'] > 'C')
```

When I checked the cat_dtype object, the order is clearly correct when 'A+' being the largest and 'D' being the smallest. When I compare the values under column 'Grades' with 'C', the result doesn't match the order. What gives?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fi45.png)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to assign the 'astype' to df['Grades']

```
df['Grades'] = df['Grades'].astype(cat_dtype)
```

Filtering on your criteria outputs as:

```
df[df['Grades'] > 'C']


            Grades
excellent   A+
excellent   A
excellent   A-
good        B+
good        B
good        B-
ok          C+
```

Comment: OMG, I am such a beginner. I actually had this but forgot to assign the newly cast data to the original dataframe! Thanks~~~

Comment: No shame -- happens all the time! :)